# OperationalError: ERROR: pgbouncer cannot connect to server

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I'm trying to do `python manage.py syncdb` on a Django installation, but I keep getting `OperationalError: ERROR:  pgbouncer cannot connect to server`. pgbouncer.log contains lines such as:

```
2017-09-19 19:44:15.107 1128 LOG C-0x8a9930: mydb/myuser@unix:6432 closing because: pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0)
2017-09-19 19:44:15.107 1128 WARNING C-0x8a9930: mydb/myuser@unix:6432 Pooler Error: pgbouncer cannot connect to server
2017-09-19 19:44:15.107 1128 LOG S-0x8c72e0: mydb/myuser@35.154.149.188:5432 new connection to server
2017-09-19 19:44:15.107 1128 LOG C-0x8a9930: mydb/myuser@unix:6432 login failed: db=mydb user=myuser
2017-09-19 19:44:30.108 1128 LOG S-0x8c72e0: mydb/myuser@35.154.149.188:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=15)
```

In case needed, `ps -aef | grep pgbouncer` yields:

```
postgres  1128     1  0 18:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pgbouncer -d /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
myuser    1919  1533  0 19:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pgbouncer
```

Moreover, `grep port /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini` results in:

```
;;   dbname= host= port= user= password=
mydb = host=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=mydb
;forcedb = host=127.0.0.1 port=300 user=baz password=foo client_encoding=UNICODE datestyle=ISO connect_query='SELECT 1'
listen_port = 6432
```

Lastly, the relevant parts of `settings.py` contain:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '/var/run/postgresql',
        'PORT': '6432',
    }
```

---

I turned `log_connections` to `on` in postgresql.conf, restarted PG and tried again. Here's the relevant lines:

```
2017-09-20 07:50:59 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-09-20 07:50:59 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-09-20 07:51:00 UTC LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2017-09-20 07:51:00 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-09-20 07:51:00 UTC LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2017-09-20 07:51:00 UTC LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2017-09-20 07:51:01 UTC LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2017-09-20 07:51:01 UTC LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2017-09-20 07:51:01 UTC LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2017-09-20 07:51:01 UTC LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
```

It seems the connection is going through, but the `user` and `database` name is `postgres`. Those credentials aren't what I supplied in `pgbouncer.ini`.

However, explicitly adding `myuser` in the connection string described in `pgbouncer.ini` leads to:

```
2017-09-20 09:37:37 UTC FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
2017-09-20 09:37:37 UTC DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 90: "local   all             all                                     peer"
```

Totally stumped.

Comment: What do the PostgreSQL logs say about that? Is PostgreSQL running at the destination?

Comment: You didn't read the first part of my comment. Turn `log_connections` to `on` and check the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: settings.py has socket directory defined as host, yet you have localhost in `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini` - change `/var/run/postgresql` to `127.0.0.1` please in `settings.py`

Comment: @VaoTsun: ah no, that didn't work. For the record, I've set `unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql` in pgbouncer.ini, so socket should work. Maybe `pgbouncer.ini` isn't loading correctly when I do `sudo service pgbouncer start`?  Either that, or there's a permissions issue here. What do you feel?

Comment: `ps -aef | grep pgbouncer` shows right config. what do you have in `auth_hba_file`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: Well I don't use that file. My auth file is set to `/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt` in `pgbouncer.ini` (with `auth_type=md5`). userlist.txt contains `"myuser" "mypassword"` (matches `settings.py`).

Comment: there are no connections for myuser in postgres logs - did you switch `log_connections` on postgres.conf as Laurenz asked?

Comment: Yes I did. Notice the logs I pasted at the end of the question. There are connections being generated for `postgres` instead. That's what comes up when I try to use pgbouncer right now. Thing is, I'm not trying to connect to DB `postgres` via user `posgres`. I'm trying to connect to db `mydb` via user `myuser`. There's some kind of misconfiguration - which is leading me to believe my pgbouncer.ini is either incomplete or loading incorrectly. Maybe I should explicitly add `user=myuser` to the connection string in `pgbouncer.ini`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154871/discussion-between-hassan-baig-and-vao-tsun).

Comment: @VaoTsun: it worked. And you know what I changed in the end? I was setting `'PORT' : '6432'` in `settings.py` (also shown in my question). I simply commented out that line. It's working now. I'm not sure why it's working however. Perhaps some kind of collision of ports going on in the test server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the mis-configuration emanated from this line in `settings.py`:

```
'PORT': '6432',
```

I commented it and pgbouncer started working.

Though I'm not sure 'why'.

Maybe there's a collision on this port; Pgbouncer and PG coexist on a single server in my case. I've set them up over different VMs in the past without a hitch (and without needing to comment `'PORT': '6432',`)

Comment: That's very strange. I suspect that with commented PORT you connected directly to postgresql

Comment: You can check your pgbouncer config for port with `sudo cat /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini | grep listen_port`. That is where you want to connect.

Comment: 6432 is usually pgbouncer, if you comment it out then it is 5432 which is postgres directly.